# How do I stop a running music thread in Java?

Tags: java, audio

I have a class that plays background music on infinite loop for a game. I want it to stop when another class calls the stopPlaying() method on the BackgroundMusic object. According to Oracle docs, there is no way to stop a thread in Java.

It said to use a variable that it checks and stops when the variable is a certain value. I tried making a boolean running that gets set to false when I call stopPlaying() and tried making the while loop have running as the condition instead of true, but that did not work without a delay. (Message edited from before)

I would put my class in here, but this site keeps saying it's not formatted properly, and I've done this before (pasting from Eclipse). I put it on PasteBin: http://pastebin.com/edCH2DXE

Comment: The boolean solution should work. Try to add your code and we can help you check what is wrong.

Comment: Remember that the boolean needs to be `volatile`, otherwise it may be cached and the music thread will never see its value change.

Comment: _I would put my class in here, but this site keeps saying it's not formatted properly, and I've done this before._ Try to put int on [PasteBin](http://pastebin.com/) and paste your link in the question

Comment: How to format code for SO in 3 easy steps:  1) Use your text editor to replace TAB characters with the required number of SPACE characters.  Ideally, line wrap it to 80 characters so that you don't get horizontal scroll bars.  2)  Cut and paste into the SO editor pane.  3)  Select the code you just pasted, and click the "Code Sample" button at the top of the edit pane.  The one that looks like "{ }".  4) Does it look OK in the preview?

Comment: @StephenC  Good advice.  One note though.  I've never had any problems posting code with tabs (as TextPad generally uses) or space characters (as Netbeans uses by default).  It all comes out looking the same.

Comment: @Thomas Oh, didn't know about volatile variables. That did work, but there's about 2 seconds of delay before the music actually stops when I do that.

Comment: You're buffering and sending 128000 bytes at a time to the output device. The `write` call blocks until that is played, or maybe until there is enough space in its output buffer, so your `while` loop condition only gets checked once in a while. Try writing in smaller chunks.

Answer (score 1):

It's kind of a big hammer, but you can *interrupt* the thread by calling `musicThread.interrupt()`. This will cause `isInterrupted()` to return `true` for the music thread. If the thread was doing some blocking I/O at the time, this might cause `InterruptedException` to be thrown, so you need to catch that as well:

```
  try {
    while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
       // play music
    }
  } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
    // any cleanup necessary
  }
```

Again, it's a big hammer, and it's better to use the boolean flag approach if you can.

Comment: I tried doing that, but it doesn't stop the music from playing.

Comment: Threading APIs tend to not provide explicit mechanisms to kill threads because the results of doing so can be very unpredictable.  What if the thread was terminated holding resources?   For this reason, the approach is always to arrange an interruption or destroy the resources the thread is blocked on.
In the case of an audio player, suddenly stopping it will result in an audible click - what is really needed is a ramp-down of the gain over about 250ms.

Comment: Quitting the java process while the program is running results in - even worse - a nasty static sound for a split second. Fixable, but the interrupt() method just isn't stopping it for me anyway.